# Calendar app Flipview controls

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm building a Windows 8 app and have come to a point where I don't understand how to solve my problem. (I'm new to C# development in general, so some things are more foreign to me not counting the new WIN-RT paradigms)

I've created a XAML file that displays 1 week (Sunday - Saturday) and populates each day column with the date of the month for that day (20-27 for ex.) for right now, it just makes a new Calendar object and uses the current date.

**Here's my problem:**
I'd like to implement a flipview to change from week to week, forward and backwards in time (this is very similar to the functionality in the Windows 8 Calendar app)

I do not know how to move from one week to another, because most demos online use image file resources. I want to move to the same XAML file I have, with just differently populated number fields, etc.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since FlipView is an ItemsControl - you can use the same method you would use when populating lists - use an ItemsSource to bind to a collection of weeks and specify an ItemTemplate/DataTemplate that will display the week view.

Ultimately you might hit some issues with the fact that a calendar should not really be a list with a beginning and an end. Perhaps you could implement some pseudo-virtualization hack, but ultimately it would probably be better for you to implement your own interaction logic.

Comment: Is that something i can create progamatically in the code behind for this week.xaml? I think that would allow me to edit the list on the fly to keep up with a user going forward/backwards in time, as well as keeping the list relatively short.

I'm not even sure where I'd start with the interaction logic you mention - like I said I'm new to this entire environment so I don't quite know what's possible.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can set ManipulationMode=TranslateX and then handle ManipulationDelta/Started/Completed events to update a RenderTransform/TranslateTransform on your control to enable swiping between weeks. Then you might also want to add buttons to allow users to tap/click to switch to previous or next week as the FlipView control does. You would probably also want to use Storyboards/DoubleAnimations to complete week transitions with animations.

Comment: I'm trying to stay with the FlipView as it is if possible - I have some feeling like MS found a way to do this with their calendar app. 

I've managed to get this working for going forward in time ( I can just progamatically add to the list each time you go forward, which works fine), but obviously going back in time poses a problem as I'd  have to add to the beginning of the list - something that doesn't seem to be allowed, and replacing the list entirely breaks the program. Any ideas to continue down this path?

Comment: Not sure, but the calendar seems to be an HTML app, so even if it looks and works similar - it might be implemented in completely different way.